# Can't set default_dataset in bigquery.QueryJobConfig() as string

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to construct a bigquery.QueryJobConfig() object with a default dataset. The code should be

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
stackoverflow_dataset_id = 'bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow'
job_query_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(default_dataset = stackoverflow_dataset_id)
```

and I used it before without any issue. However, today I installed a new conda environment and this I get this very cryptic error message instead

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-68b87871aaed>", line 1, in <module>
    job_query_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(default_dataset = stackoverflow_dataset_id)

  File "/Users/dabol99/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 1944, in __init__
    super(QueryJobConfig, self).__init__("query", **kwargs)

  File "/Users/dabol99/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 732, in __init__
    setattr(self, prop, val)

  File "/Users/dabol99/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 2014, in default_dataset
    resource = value.to_api_repr()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_api_repr'
```

Maybe I am missing a dependency, but I can't figure out which one from the error message.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I was not setting up my conda environment properly. Updating all modules to the last version solved the issue.